# Is it possible to declare dynamic constants in Laravel models using records for the model?

Tags: php, laravel

Say for instance I have a status model and I want to create constants from the status table using the status specific field records

```
class Status extends BaseModel
 {
    protected $table = 'Status';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    //here or in the constructor, I wants to query records for the same model then declare constants like
     foreach($records as $key => val){
       const $key = $val;
     }
 }
```

Comment: No, it is __not__ possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lack in basic programming knowledge.

A const variable is supposed to never change
A static variable is supposed to be accessed as class member without initializating class (using a `new` keyword)
A non-static non-const variable is accessible only after initializating  a class with `new` keyword

You probably want to replace a bad

```
const $key = $val;
```

with

```
$this->$key = $val;
```

Which will work in Laravel

```
class Status extends BaseModel
{
    protected $table = 'Status';

    public function __construct(array $attributes) {
        parent::__construct($attributes);

        $records = [
            'some_reflected_field_1'  = 100,
            'some_reflected_field_2'  = 101,
            'some_reflected_field_3'  = 102
        ];

        foreach($records as $key => val) {
            $this->$key = $val;
        }
    }
}
```

Execution:

```
$foo = new Status([
    'name'  => 'active'
]);

echo $foo->some_reflected_field_2; // 101
```

Comment: A question implies that there is lack of knowledge

Comment: A question is soliciting an explanation, not an attack.